# "Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established" - Neo4j/GraphQL

Tags: neo4j, graphql, nestjs

Starting up NestJS & GraphQL using `yarn start:dev` using `await app.listen(3200);`. When trying to connect to my Neo4J Desktop, I get this error trying to get my queries at `localhost:3200/graphQL`:

```
 "errors": [
   {
     "message": "Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established",
     "locations": [
       {
         "line": 2,
         "column": 3
       }
     ],
     "path": [
       "getMovies"
     ],
     "extensions": {
       "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
       "exception": {
         "code": "ServiceUnavailable",
         "name": "Neo4jError"
       }
     }
   }
 ],
 "data": null
}
```

So I figured my local Neo4J desktop graph is not running correctly, but I can't seem to find any answer how to solve it.. Currently I have a `config.ts` file which has:

```
export const HOSTNAME = 'localhost';
export const NEO4J_USER = 'neo4j';
export const NEO4J_PASSWORD = '123';
```

and a file `neogql.resolver.ts`:

```
import {
  Resolver,
  Query,
  Args,
  ResolveProperty,
  Parent,
} from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { HOSTNAME, NEO4J_USER, NEO4J_PASSWORD } from '../config';
import { Movie } from '../graphql';
import { Connection, relation, node } from 'cypher-query-builder';
import { NotFoundException } from '@nestjs/common';
const db = new Connection(`bolt://${HOSTNAME}`, {
  username: NEO4J_USER,
  password: NEO4J_PASSWORD,
});
@Resolver('Movie')
export class NeogqlResolver {
  @Query()
  async getMovies(): Promise<Movie> {
    const movies = (await db
      .matchNode('movies', 'Movie')
      .return([
        {
          movies: [{ id: 'id', title: 'title', year: 'year' }],
        },
      ])
      .run()) as any;
return movies;
  }
@Query('movie')
  async getMovieById(
    @Args('id')
    id: string,
  ): Promise<any> {
    const movie = (await db
      .matchNode('movie', 'Movie')
      .where({ 'movie.id': id })
      .return([
        {
          movie: [{ id: 'id', title: 'title', year: 'year' }],
        },
      ])
      .run<any>()) as any;
if (movie.length === 0) {
      throw new NotFoundException(
        `Movie id '${id}' does not exist in database `,
      );
    }
return movie[0];
  }
@ResolveProperty()
  async actors(@Parent() movie: any) {
    const { id } = movie;
return (await db
      .match([node('actors', 'Actor'), relation('in'), node('movie', 'Movie')])
      .where({ 'movie.id': id })
      .return([
        {
          actors: [
            {
              id: 'id',
              name: 'name',
              born: 'born',
            },
          ],
        },
      ])
      .run()) as any;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with grandSTACK when running against a neo4j version 4 server. According to Will Lyon this is due to mismatched encryption defaults between driver and database: https://community.neo4j.com/t/migrating-an-old-grandstack-project-to-neo4j-4/16911/2

So passing a config object with

```
{ encrypted: "ENCRYPTION_OFF"}
```

to the Connection constructor should do the trick.

Comment: Ok, the problem is I don't use a driver currently so I am not entirely sure where to insert { encrypted: "ENCRYPTION_OFF"}. I did some trial and error but it ended up complaining on "encrypted" as non existent type or similar.

Comment: The driver is in the Connection class that you import from 'cypher-query-builder', and from a quick look at the source code it seems that the constructor takes an optional third argument with configuration. I don't use cypher-query-builder, but this could work:
`const db = new Connection(`bolt://${HOSTNAME}`, {
   username: NEO4J_USER,
   password: NEO4J_PASSWORD,
 }, { 
  encrypted: "ENCRYPTION_OFF"
});`

Comment: You need to pass another object after your credentials with `{
    driverConfig: {
      encrypted: 'ENCRYPTION_OFF',
    },
  },`

Answer (score 3):

Be sure to pass the Config object like this:

```
var hostname = this.configService.get<string>('NEO4J_URL');
var username = this.configService.get<string>('NEO4J_USERNAME');
var password = this.configService.get<string>('NEO4J_PASSWORD');

db = new Connection(`${hostname}`, {
        username: username,
        password: password,
    }, { 
        driverConfig: { encrypted: "ENCRYPTION_OFF" }
    });
```